# assigning values to a matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to store this:

```
for i in range(len(cpi)):
    print((cf[:i+1] / cpi[i]).astype(int))
```

Into a matrix. I tried this:

```
payment = np.zeros((len(cpi), len(cpi)))
for i in range(len(cpi)):
    payment = cf[:i+1] / cpi[i]).astype(int)
```

But that gives me the wrong matrix that looks like this:

```
[[0 1 0 ..., 1 0 3]
 [2 9 2 ..., 4 0 4]
 [4 0 8 ..., 9 6 3]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [1 3 0 ..., 1 1 1]
 [0 3 0 ..., 1 0 0]]
```

When the output show be this:

```
[[0 1 0 1 1 1 0 5 1 0 2]]
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1]
 [1 3 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1]]
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 2 0 2 1 1 0 2 1 0]]
[[0 1 0 1 1 1 0 5 1 0 2]
 [1 6 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 2]
```

Note that is not all the elements just some of them.

Comment: Your code is just assigning some values to the `payment` variable name in the loop.  It isn't modifying the initial `payment` array.  You need to accumulate values in a list.  You may need to revisit some basic Python tutorials.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes most likely I normally code in C++ and I am new to python. Perhaps you can help me by providing an answer?

Comment: In Python assignment just links the name to an object.  So there's no need to 'initialize' a viable - unless you intend to mutate it, that is, change it in-place.  To replicate the `print`, I'd suggest starting with a list, `alist=[]`, and appending values to it in the list, `alist.append(cf[:i+1] / cpi[i]).astype(int))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are assigning new value to payment variable each time you loop, when you actually want to just append to it. For example (not tested):

```
payment=[]
for i in range(len(cpi)):
    payment.append((cf[:i+1] / cpi[i]).astype(int))
```